# Jquery on select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following **JS code:**

```
$("#idserver").change(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

**idserver:**

```
<select id="idserver" name="serverid">
  <option value='0'>number one</option>
  <option value='1'>number two</option>
</select>
```

**checkboxes:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="calc" name="access[a]" value="2" />example
```

and simply doesn't work

Comment: I don't see a checked attribute on your checkbox.

Comment: Use `console.log('reached here');` inside `change` function, to check whether control reaches inside it.

Comment: It works for me

http://jsfiddle.net/agqxhgmg/

Comment: it's working fine .
see here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/gn65qfwm/

Comment: already working in every browser(IE/Chrome/FF) http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/mjnpu5n1/

Comment: jbrahy there are no need of checked attribute define in checkbox its not necessary.

Comment: Благовест Тодоров your code is correct and will have to work.

check in console may be there are any other js error before it.(click F12 in chrome and go to console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your code working fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/198ojxms/) may be your console will tell you what is the error.

Also you have not checked your checkbox by default add `checked` attribute in your checkbox

I assume that may be you have not included js library or you have not written your code inside ready function, try this:

Inlcude **[jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/)** on top :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<select id="idserver" name="serverid">
<option value='0'>number one</option>
<option value='1'>number two</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="calc" name="access[a]" value="2" checked />example
```

**jQuery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#idserver").change(function(){
             $('input:checkbox').prop( "checked", false );
       });

});

</script>
```

Here is the live demo : **[jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b518jw48/1/)**

Comment: Js is included, i copied and pasted everything from you comment and still doesn't unselect checkboxes

Comment: @БлаговестТодоров add `checked` attribute to your checkbox and see it works or not

Comment: @Brian people should unerstand when should [downvote the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: You're welcome @БлаговестТодоров, if you used my answer.. you marked the wrong one correct :)

Answer (score 0):

U must type like this

```
$("#idserver").change(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop( "checked", false );
});
```

Comment: nothing issue issue in `op` code, can you say reason

Comment: No, removeAttr works has the same effect and is not the issue. Prop is probably a better way of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

here try this

```
$("#idserver").change(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `document ready` block:

```
$(function () {//<-- document ready
    $("#idserver").change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="idserver" name="serverid">
<option value='0'>number one</option>
<option value='1'>number two</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="calc" name="access[a]" value="2" />example

$("#idserver").change(function(){
   $('input:checkbox').prop( "checked", false );
});
```

Check above code

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/0z7xama3/)

Comment: nothing wrong... it's working in as usual code.. but i changed with prop instead removeattr

Comment: removeAttr works and has the same effect and is not the issue. Prop is a better way of doing it though.